# Question from Munkres Topology Regarding the Product Topology (Section 16, Exercise 5)

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ and $X'$ denote a single set in the topologies $\mathscr T$ and $\mathscr T'$ respectively; let $Y$ and $Y'$ denote a single set in the topologies $\mathscr U$ and $\mathscr U'$ respectively.  Assume these sets are non-empty.

a) Show that if $\mathscr T'\supseteq\mathscr T$ and $\mathscr U'\supseteq\mathscr U$, then the product toplogy on $X'\times Y'$ is finer than the topology on $X\times Y$.

Having trouble making sense of this problem.  How can I compare the topologies if they are on different sets.?

Comment: They aren't on different sets.  As sets X=X', and Y=Y'

Comment: I think maybe $X=X'$ and $Y=Y'$ in terms of sets. The notation is to distinguish different topological spaces.

Comment: Yes, thank you Seth and Starlight. I was misunderstanding the notation.

Comment: I became confused on this problem as well since he does make it sound like there is some topological space (Z,t) and (Z,t') where X,X',Y,Y' are elements of the topology. I would think to then talk about their product topology you would first have to define topologies on X,X',Y,Y', perhaps with the subspace topology or something like that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The notation is a bit confusing. As a topological space is just a pair $(X, \mathcal{T})$ it would have been better stated, I think, as follows:

Suppose we have non-empty topological spaces $(X,\mathcal{T})$ and $(X,\mathcal{T}')$ and another pair of non-empty topological spaces $(Y,\mathcal{U})$ and $(Y,\mathcal{U}')$.

As an auxiliary notation, denote the product topology of two topologies $\mathcal{T}$ and $\mathcal{U}$ by $\mathcal{T} \otimes \mathcal{U}$. As you probably know, this is the smallest topology on $X \times Y$ that contains the set $\{U \times V: U \in \mathcal{T}, V \in \mathcal{U} \}$.

If $\mathcal{T} \subseteq \mathcal{T}'$ and $\mathcal{U} \subseteq \mathcal{U}'$, then the product topological space $(X \times Y, \mathcal{T}' \otimes \mathcal{U}')$ has a finer topology than $(X \times  Y, \mathcal{T} \otimes \mathcal{U})$, or more succinctly: $\mathcal{T} \otimes \mathcal{U} \subseteq \mathcal{T}' \otimes \mathcal{U}'$.

Comment: Thanks for the enlightening answer.  I notice that the same notation use for the product topology is also used for the product of $\sigma$-algebras in Folland's Real Analysis.  Are these notations standard?

Comment: I've seen it used mostly for $\sigma$-algebras.